How can I update data in a SharePoint list via Connection in Excel?
I have a Connection to a SharePoint list and, accordingly, a table in Excel that contains data from SharePoint. Let's say I add a new row of data to this table. How can I sync my table with SharePoint? I tried refreshing the table, but this only resulted in the removal of new data in the table, since the data was simply replaced with data from SharePoint.

I think your best bet is to use Power Automate.
If the list is on a SharePoint site, you can tell Power Automate to trigger on the items when changes or made. You can ask the Power Automate experts here: Power automate community.

There is no native way to achieve this. You need programming or a third party tool.
We used to sell our software Synchronizer for Excel and SharePoint for this, but it has been discontinued. If you fill the contact form, there are still options to purchase it until the end of 2024.
